# Strange delay for http requests on my local network

Tags: networking, http

When trying to access the configuration page of my router (192.168.1.1) or the website hosted on a vm I'm running, there is an initial delay of about 10 seconds and then the request fails. On reload, it then loads instantly.

What's causing this?

Comment: Its a VM. A million things could be going wrong. Experiment with the bridged/NAT settings for the network card as a starting point.

Comment: are you using a hostname or an ip address in your url? could be DNS related.